# Getting javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException when I call getListItems when I Include query In Java

Tags: java, sharepoint, soap-client

I am working with Sharepoint SOAP service to get the data on the bases of the query.
I am getting a list of documents when I pass Query parameter as null in GetListItems, but when I pass Query it is giving me following error message.

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.internal.w's. fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:119)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.internal. w's.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
at $Proxy30.getListItems(Unknown Source)
```

Code and Input are as follow.

`GetListItems.ViewFields viewFields = new ViewFields();
 viewFields.getContent().add("<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>");

 GetListItems.Query query = new Query();
 query.getContent().add("<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Text'>3</Value>   </Eq></Where></Query>");`

and This the way I am calling to the Sharepoint service

```
port.getListItems(listName, "", query, viewFields, rowLimit, null, null);
```

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. As follow.

We are passing a string as parameter in the Query class constructor, instead of we need to pass Element class objects. So I have crated one method to return the Element Object Code is as follow.

```
public static Element generateXmlNode(String sXML) throws   ParserConfigurationException,SAXException, IOException {
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document documentOptions = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(sXML)));
Element elementOptions = documentOptions.getDocumentElement();
return elementOptions;
}
```

and Instead of `"<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Text'>3</Value> </Eq></Where></Query>"`

I am passing `generateXmlNode("<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Text'>3</Value> </Eq></Where></Query>")`

This has resolved my issue.

Referenced from http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-java-tutorial/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Value Type to `<Value type='Counter'>`.

Comment: You can try caml query designers e.g.: [this](http://sharepoint.biwug.be/SitePages/Caml_Designer.aspx) and use generated query.